# GitKraken - push by default to a folder within remote origin

Tags: git, settings, git-remote, gitkraken

I've just started a new job where they use GitKraken. In the Remote origin we have a bunch of versions, and for each bug/feature we're going to work on we create a separated branch, which are placed within the feature subfolder in origin. Here a screenshot of that:
[image]

When I now create a new branch, and then want to push it to this origin, I get the following:
[image]

As you can see, it by default suggests to push it to origin, which is good, but after the slash it mentions the branch name directly as placeholder within the input-field.

I now change this input-field from the default (placeholder) `abc-4398-abcdef` to a manual typed `feature/abc-4398-abcdef`, but I wonder if there is a QOL option available in GitKraken to ALWAYS push to the feature branch within origin by default, unless manually changed? That way I could just click pull + submit in GitKraken, instead of having to type out `feature/abc-1234-abcdef` manually every time I want to push a new feature/bug branch to origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new remote branch, the default name for the remote branch is the name of your local branch.

My guess is : the local branch you created is named `abc-1234-abcdef`.

Name it `feature/abc-1234-abcdef` instead, and the default name for the remote branch will be what you expect.

Comment: Thanks. That indeed seems to work! :) I still have to type `feature/` every time I create a branch, but that's better than typing the branch-name including ticket number twice, both when I create and push it to origin.